# Getting "Could not open input file" when trying to use PHPUnit with NetBeans and Xampp

Tags: netbeans, phpunit

I just installed a fresh setup of NetBeans 7.0.1 and the latest Xampp package.  When I click Tools > Create Unit Tests on a file or class I get the following error in the output:

Could not open input file: .\pear\PHPUnit2\TextUI\TestRunner.php

This file is present and I can run the phpunit.bat from Explorer.  I've wasted over an hour trying to find out why this is happening...  Has anyone else had this problem?

Steve

Comment: The latest PHPUnit is 3.5.15. Version 2 is extremely old. While it does appear that NetBeans is at least seeing `phpunit.bat`, you might want to see if you have two versions of PHPUnit installed.

Comment: @DavidHarkness imho you should post that as an answer. There is nothing more to say about this and no other help can be given (that I'd be aware of)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest PHPUnit is 3.5.15. Version 2 is extremely old. While it does appear that NetBeans is at least seeing `phpunit.bat`, you might want to see if you have two versions of PHPUnit installed.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed the latest distribution of Xampp would come with a reasonably recent version of PEAR and libraries it includes, apparently not.  Updating PEAR and PHPUnit fixed the problem, although it was a little confusing since I'm not really used to PHP.

Comment: Wow, so XAMPP was the culprit to install an old version? Very odd since it was the latest version of XAMPP. I've only used PHP on Linux where it's a little more straight-forward.

Answer (score 1):

You can always try to update the paths and make them absolute instead of relative:

```
"C:\xampp\php\.\php.exe" ".\pear\PHPUnit2\TextUI\TestRunner.php" %*
```

to something like this, minding your own file structure of course.

```
"C:\xampp\php\php.exe" "C:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit2\TextUI\TestRunner.php" %*
```